# Traverse javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript array of objects as follows :

```
list = [
            {
                "employee_work_rights_id":74,
                "amazon_id":173,
                "employee_id":3,
                "work_rights":"australian_citizen",
                "document_type":"password",
                "display_name":"a.pdf",
                "filename":"abc.pdf",
                "s3bucket":"xyz",
                "filepath":"employer27\/employee3\/"

            },

            {
                "employee_work_rights_id":75,
                "amazon_id":175,
                "employee_id":3,
                "work_rights":"australian_citizen",
                "document_type":"password",
                "display_name":"a.pdf",
                "filename":"xyz.pdf",
                "s3bucket":"zyx",
                "filepath":"employer27\/employee3\/"
            }
        ]
```

I tried to access amazon_id as follows :

```
console.log(list[0].amazon_id);
```

This is giving me undefined. How can I access this ?

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(list[0])`?

Comment: No, this prints 173.

Comment: Hi, @Tushar I am getting undefined

Comment: works fine for me. May be you're trying to get it with async request?

Comment: @Tanvir Can you create live demo

Answer (score 3):

You're doing the right thing. The way you initialize `list` is correct, and so is the way you access the property.

Assuming you were trying interactively in the console, the `undefined` you see is not the value of `list[0].amazon_id`. It's the return value of `console.log`. In Javascript, everything has a return value. However, in the console, just above or just below your `undefined`, you should see amazon_id's proper value.

Comment: A big stab in the dark this one is... :)

Comment: There's some extrapolation indeed, but it's the only reasonable one. :)

Comment: Well, there's also the good old http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/476... :)

Comment: Not here, no. Accessing an unexisting property inside an unexisting list would throw an exception. So we're not likely in the case where variable scope has been badly handled or understood.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MathiasDolidon. After reading your comment, I checked console again and debugged it with debugger. What happened is there was a double quote " before the array. Console does not print that. Here I have just copy pasted the array so here it is working correctly.                                   I have to $.parseJSON() this for the correct answer. However, your answer triggered the solution. Upvoted you.  :)

Comment: Well then honestly the stab in the dark missed its target nonetheless and Deceze was right. :D

Comment: @Tanvir : when debugging JS, each browser has its pros/cons. When it comes to console.log, you'll notice that Firefox is very explicit about telling you the exact type of what's printed. When you console.log an array, you'll get `Array [...]`. Not so with Chrome, which only gives you a subtle hint with italic characters. Might help to know it.